# Best practices to add some data into queue

Tags: c#, asp.net, queue, message-queue, priority-queue

I have a web application where users can upload the photo. I do have a windows service running which takes the uploaded photo  and crops it to different sizes. This runs in a specified interval. Photo will be visible to the user once after it's cropped. So once user uploads the photo and photo cropper has not yet run, they wont be able to see the photo. Due to this behaviour user thinks that there was some error uploading the photo and they will upload it again and again.

Can any one suggest me some queuing mechanism where the photocropper runs immediately when the user uploads the photos which is queued.

I am using asp.net & C#.

Please let me know if i am confusing.

Comment: Why you not show him a wait page / a signal , and after the image is ok reload the page with the image ?

Comment: for most of the questions i set the answers by clickimg the tick mark. there are some questions which i haven't got any answers.. what can i do with those questions?

Answer (score 2):

Using NService bus is a best option I think.Using NService bus you can handle a message as soon as it is avliable in queue.You can host your NService application as a window service as well. [NSerivice Bus](http://www.nservicebus.com/)

Comment: Nservice vs MSMQ.. according to you will gives more performance?

Comment: finally i decided to user Nservice Bus. I should be able to send prioritize the queue? How can i do this?

Comment: @Nimesh: Basically the Idea is this you have to publish a message to a queue using NService bus from your web application.Then you have to create another NService application (basically an class library , you would see how to do that from the documentation) which will subscribe to the queue.This application will be responsible for handling and processing of the message you sent to the queue.

Comment: @Nimesh:You dont have to create a Windows service as such,create an NService application (a class library) and you can host it as a windows service.

Comment: Thanks a lot... May i know how can i set the priority for the messages that i am sending to msmq via Nservice Bus?

Comment: @Nimesh: I dont know much about the Priority messages,but hopefully this link http://www.nservicebus.com/Distributor.aspx might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ) is natively available in .Net.  You can pass in your own types and read them out in your Windows Service as long as you have a shared DLL containing a common interface / the concrete implementation.

Obviously it needs to be installed on the server, but is generally part of the default installation.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think that what you are trying to do - crop a photo that is uploaded, should't take too long, and as someone suggested on the comment to the question, do you need the overhead of creating an infrastructure where the work is queued and processed out-of-process by another application? Is this going to happen a lot (how many photo crop requests per sec/min?). Instead can you not just send the request via AJAX to the server, and have some form of "please wait" animation on the browser until the request eventually comes back and the photo is cropped?

If you do think you need to go down the queue approach, then I'd suggest MSMQ, because it's very simple to work with - see the example code [here](http://www.vcskicks.com/ms-queue.php)